# How to add integer (seconds) to hh:mm:ss format in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following data frame in python where am trying to compute column 'New time' by adding 'Duration' (which is in seconds) to the 'start_time'

```
Serial  start_date     start_time     Duration(seconds)  New time
    A   5/22/2017       10:37:24        216 
    A   5/22/2017       10:37:26        213 
    A   5/22/2017       10:37:29         3  
    A   5/22/2017       10:39:55         60 
    A   5/22/2017       10:51:50        380 
    A   5/22/2017       10:51:57        339
```

I want to add duration into start_time. The duration is in seconds.
'New time' is expected in hh:mm:ss format.

I tried looking for similar queries in the forum but could not get around this.

Below is the info

```
data.info()

start_date         13661 non-null object
start_time         13661 non-null object
Duration           13661 non-null int64
```

I tried taking a cue from a similar problem in the forum, using datetime

```
data.newtime = data.start_time + datetime.timedelta(data.Duration)
```

when i execute this am getting the following error :     TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: Series

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-95-fdfac1490ba5> in <module>()
----> 1 data.newtime = data.start_time + datetime.timedelta(data.Duration)

TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: Series
```

Not sure how to go about it. New to python.

Help appreciated
TIA

Comment: @MaximilianPeters I tried referring that. Here I want to compute this for each row time entry in the data frame. I have edited this with the error am getting.

Comment: Thanks! Now the question is clear.

Comment: Be aware that if you are doing this on logging data that the presence of leap seconds (that Python ignores) can throw off your calculations.  Usually only important in physics experiments and financial transaction timestamps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and output is `timedelta` too:

```
df['New time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['start_time']) + 
                 pd.to_timedelta(df['Duration(seconds)'], unit='s')
print (df)
  Serial start_date start_time  Duration(seconds) New time
0      A  5/22/2017   10:37:24                216 10:41:00
1      A  5/22/2017   10:37:26                213 10:40:59
2      A  5/22/2017   10:37:29                  3 10:37:32
3      A  5/22/2017   10:39:55                 60 10:40:55
4      A  5/22/2017   10:51:50                380 10:58:10
5      A  5/22/2017   10:51:57                339 10:57:36
```

But if seconds is more, output is changed, because there are also days:

```
print (df)
  Serial start_date start_time  Duration(seconds)
0      A  5/22/2017   10:37:24                216
1      A  5/22/2017   10:37:26             213000
2      A  5/22/2017   10:37:29                  3
3      A  5/22/2017   10:39:55                 60
4      A  5/22/2017   10:51:50                380
5      A  5/22/2017   10:51:57                339

df['New time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['start_time']) + 
                 pd.to_timedelta(df['Duration(seconds)'], unit='s')
print (df)
  Serial start_date start_time  Duration(seconds)        New time
0      A  5/22/2017   10:37:24                216 0 days 10:41:00
1      A  5/22/2017   10:37:26             213000 2 days 21:47:26
2      A  5/22/2017   10:37:29                  3 0 days 10:37:32
3      A  5/22/2017   10:39:55                 60 0 days 10:40:55
4      A  5/22/2017   10:51:50                380 0 days 10:58:10
5      A  5/22/2017   10:51:57                339 0 days 10:57:36
```

---

Also is posible add datetime:

```
df['New date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date']) + \
                 pd.to_timedelta(df['start_time']) +  \
                 pd.to_timedelta(df['Duration(seconds)'], unit='s')
print (df)
  Serial start_date start_time  Duration(seconds)            New date
0      A  5/22/2017   10:37:24                216 2017-05-22 10:41:00
1      A  5/22/2017   10:37:26                213 2017-05-22 10:40:59
2      A  5/22/2017   10:37:29                  3 2017-05-22 10:37:32
3      A  5/22/2017   10:39:55                 60 2017-05-22 10:40:55
4      A  5/22/2017   10:51:50                380 2017-05-22 10:58:10
5      A  5/22/2017   10:51:57                339 2017-05-22 10:57:36
```

---

```
df['New date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date']) + \
                 pd.to_timedelta(df['start_time']) +  \
                 pd.to_timedelta(df['Duration(seconds)'], unit='s')
print (df)
  Serial start_date start_time  Duration(seconds)            New date
0      A  5/22/2017   10:37:24                216 2017-05-22 10:41:00
1      A  5/22/2017   10:37:26             213000 2017-05-24 21:47:26
2      A  5/22/2017   10:37:29                  3 2017-05-22 10:37:32
3      A  5/22/2017   10:39:55                 60 2017-05-22 10:40:55
4      A  5/22/2017   10:51:50                380 2017-05-22 10:58:10
5      A  5/22/2017   10:51:57                339 2017-05-22 10:57:36
```

### ---

And if need convert `timedelta` to `string` in format `HH:MM:SS` and lost `days` (if exist):

```
df['New time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['start_time']) + 
                 pd.to_timedelta(df['Duration(seconds)'], unit='s')
df['New time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['New time']).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
print (df)
  Serial start_date start_time  Duration(seconds)  New time
0      A  5/22/2017   10:37:24                216  10:41:00
1      A  5/22/2017   10:37:26             213000  21:47:26
2      A  5/22/2017   10:37:29                  3  10:37:32
3      A  5/22/2017   10:39:55                 60  10:40:55
4      A  5/22/2017   10:51:50                380  10:58:10
5      A  5/22/2017   10:51:57                339  10:57:36
```

Comment: Glad can help! Nice day!

Comment: Got my upvote for the various options. nice one again!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet that may help you solve the problem yourself:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

my_date = datetime.strptime('5/22/2017 10:37:24', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
my_time_diff = timedelta(seconds=216)
my_new_date = my_date + my_time_diff
print(my_new_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'))
```

Useful resource:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html